# Can I use phantomJS on Azure app service for linux?

Tags: phantomjs, azure-web-app-service, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I'm getting a consistent error when trying to use the `html-pdf` package in my node application:

`StatusError: Error: spawn /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs ENOENT`

As far as I can tell everything is installed correctly and the `npm install` works as expected.   My suspicion is that there is some missing dependency in the built-in linux image, but I'm not sure how to confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information comes from the [`Download PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) page, there is two note for Linux Distributions as below.

> **Note**: For this static build, the binary is self-contained. There is no requirement to install Qt, WebKit, or any other libraries. It however still relies on Fontconfig (the package **fontconfig** or **libfontconfig**, depending on the distribution). The system must have **GLIBCXX_3.4.9** and **GLIBC_2.7**.

So the native package `fontconfig` or `libfontconfig` must have been installed in docker image first.

For Debian/Ubuntu system, you can add `RUN apt install fontconfig` in the docker file, and check the package installed whether be exists via the command `dpkg -l|grep fontconfig`.

For Fedora/CentOS system, add `RUN yum install -y fontconfig`, and check the installed on via `yum list installed|grep fontconfig`.

Comment: Are there any resources outlining how to use a custom image with azure app service?   How do I find out which type of system is being used?  My assumption is the underlying docker file being used is https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/node/blob/master/8.11.4/Dockerfile

Comment: Haven't really solved the issue, but marking as the correct answer since it aligns with my research as well.    Not sure how great of a solution this can be long term.  Microsoft installs a lot of the tooling as part of their image, so it seems like forking it is likely to cause a lot of maintenance headaches and portal incompatibilities in the future.